# Archived node_module libraries

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, libraries

I am wondering what is the best way to keep archives/older versions of a specific module I am developing for nodeJS.

Say I have SampleModule v1.0.5 then later on I will be releasing SampleModule v2.0.0. I want to retain both versions in my node_modules folder since another app will only need SampleModule v1.0.5.

What is the best way to do this? Should I just have 2 diff folders: samplemodule105 and samplemodule200 then call something like `require('samplemodule200')` or `require('samplemodule105')`?

Also, so basically `require()` checks the folder name rather than the `name` and `version` inside a module's `package.json` right? This folder and name are only used to fetch the library via `npm install`?

Comment: Usually, you keep different versions in different directories and then you reference the appropriate version by path or you "install" it into the `node_modules` directory below the app that wants to use that specific version.  If you keep your code in GitHub, you can tag each version appropriately so it can be retrieved as needed.  If you're using NPM with a private repository, you can specify all that in the package.json file and can then use NPM to "install" a specific version into the app's `node_modules` file.

Comment: You don't usually name a different version of a module with different filenames as they generally can't live in the same directory anyway (other files would conflict).

Comment: `require()` checks the entire path for equivalency before caching so different versions of the same base name can exist in different directories just fine.

Comment: How about in such case where we don't really use npm install? Our setup is we have node_modules as a shared folder (directly in C:/) and shared via symlink. Can't use npm install since our office network blocks such connectivity. So our repo is only at a shared folder.

Comment: Then, make separate shared folders for each version and vary the path that you use with `require()` to name the appropriate path to match the version you want.  This is the same way publicly available libraries like jQuery make lots of versions available (they include the version in the URL, you would include it in the path).